# Jquery UI Dialog with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, jquery-ui

I'm learning AngularJS, I searched in google but can not find even a solution to my problem.

I am using jQueryUI for dialog, bootstrap for CSS and I want AngularJS for events and queries to the database.

I have the following files:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-MX">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">    

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/demo.js"></script>

    <script src="js/angular-1.3.15/angular.js"></script>

    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Menu</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse active">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li id="mJobs"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span>JOBS</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div id="d_window"></div>   
</body>
</html>
```

file demo.js

```
$(function(){
    $( "#d_window" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      position: { my: "center", at: "center" }
    });


    $("#mJobs").click(function(){        
        $.ajax({
            url: 'views/jobs.html',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: 'content',
        }).done(function (data) {
            $( "#d_window" ).html('');
            $( "#d_window" ).append(data);
            $( "#d_window" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
    });
});
```

file jobs.html

```
<script src="js/bolsaAPP.js"></script>

<div ng-app="bolsaAPP">
<table class="table" ng-controller="bolsaView"> 
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <button id="btnEnviarBolsa" ng-click="SendJobs()" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"> Send</button>        
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

file bolsaAPP.js

```
var bolsaAPP = angular.module('bolsaAPP', [ ]);

bolsaAPP.controller('bolsaView', function($scope){
    console.log('enter');
    $scope.SendJobs = function(){
        console.log('hello');   
    };  
});
```

To give displayable send does not display anything on the console

Any idea?

Comment: This not an answer but an advice and some clues. I would really not recommend mixing angular and jQuery unless it's a directive and unless you know what you're doing. Instead i would recommend to find some good angular modules to cover your needs like this : https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To initialize an AngularJS application, you would usually place the ng-app attribute on an HTML element which defines the application's scope. As soon as the DOM content has finished loading, Angular will take care of the setup process itself and will bootstrap the application. But in case of html rendered asynchronously angular will not wait.

Luckily, AngularJS applications can also be bootstrapped programmatically.

So once you append the html to `d_window` element you should manually boostrap angular app. Try this

```
    $("#mJobs").click(function(){        
        $.ajax({
            url: 'views/jobs.html',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: 'content',
        }).done(function (data) {
            $( "#d_window" ).html('');
            $( "#d_window" ).append(data);
            $( "#d_window" ).dialog( "open" );
            angular.bootstrap(document, ["bolsaAPP"]);
        });
    });
```